# Node and AngularJs : Unable to pass data from angular to NodeJS via post

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I used [this](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html) tutorial to make a login page. My angular code looks like this.

```
app.directive('ensureUnique', ['$http', function($http) {
    console.log("In validate");
    return {
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, ele, attrs, c) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : '/email/check/' + scope.$eval(attrs.ensureUnique),
                    data : { 'field' : attrs.ensureUnique}
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, cfg){
                        c.$setValidity('unique', data.isUnique);
                    }).error(function(data, status, headers, cfg) {
                        c.$setValidity('unique', false);
                    });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and my routes file i.e **index.js** is like this.

```
app.post('/email/check/:email', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req.query);
});
```

Now i want to see this data on my Node application, so that I can verify if my email Id is unique. But I am unable to see it. It always gives me a blank object. I consulted many SO post and docs but couldn't find any answer. **What is the error here? What am I missing?**

Comment: If you check your network tab, do you see the email being added to the URL in the post?

Comment: It says undefined in my networks tab. Like /email/check/undefined

Comment: and if I remove scope.$eval from the url it says /email/check/email. Which clearly indicates that attrs.ensureUnique does not have the data to be sent. How do I send the data and not the field name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `request.query` is for the querystring content, and your email is being passed as part of the URL. Try this:

```
console.log(req.params.email);
```

Also, because you're passing the field name as data, if you're using `bodyParser` you could read it like this:

```
console.log(req.body.field);
```

**Update based on your comment:** apparently, your directive code is not without fault. If your directive attaches to an input element (this is just an assumption) then the value of that element is in the `ele` argument. So, your url should look like this:

```
url: '/email/check/' + ele.val(),
```

Comment: req.body.email gives me the field name i.e email and req.params.email gives me undefined. Which clearly implies that attrs.ensureUnique does not have a value, set How i ensure that I am sending the data?

Comment: Well it didn't work exactly. But I got a workaround. I updated the data field with ele.val() instead of in the url field. Works like a charm. Thanks a ton. If possible could you update your answer.